# Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\'

Tags: octopus-deploy

I setup a new project in Octopus Deploy but the deployment failed with the following message:

> get-itemproperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\' because it does not exist.

What would cause this error?

Answer (score 7):

This is usually because you're trying to deploy a website but IIS is not installed on the machine.